# How do I calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\partial f(x_1(t), x_2(t))}{\partial x_1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I calculate $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\dfrac{\partial f(x_1(t), x_2(t))}{\partial x_1}\right)$?
Assume the necessary differentiability conditions.

I think it's $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} \dfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial t}$, but I am not sure. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s just a direct application of the chain rule. Also you should use $d$ for differentiation wrt $t$ I think

Comment: Yes, that's right, though you could have non-partial derivatives of $x_1$ and $x_2$ with respect to $t$, as that is the only variable they depend on.

Comment: And "the necessary differentiability conditions " would include those that make the mixed partial derivatives equal, otherwise you would need $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}$ rather than $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}$.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense, actually. You're asking for the partial with respect to $x_1$ of a function of $t$. What you should be computing/writing is $$\frac d{dt} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\big(x_1(t),x_2(t)\big)\right).$$ No partials with respect to $t$, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an application of the chain rule, we have for $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ which is of class $C^1$ the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))= \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i f(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))\frac{dx_i}{dt}(t). $$
Where $\partial_j$ is the partial derivative w.r.t. the $j$-$th$ variable.
Note the multiplication here is well defined since $\frac{dx_i}{dt}(t)$ is just a scalar.

So yes, your answer is right if $f$ is of class $C^2$, why?
If $f$ is $C^2$, then
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}.$$
Your mistake could be:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2} \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1(t),x_2(t))\Big) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}(x_1(t),x_2(t)),$$
if $f$ is not of class $C^2$.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming $C^2$ so that Young's theorem applies. Thank you!